# Omnios having problems using Zone with ZFS NFS dataset

Tags: nfs, zfs, illumos, omnios

I am experimenting with Omnios trying to attempt creating a shared zfs dataset using zfs inbuilt nfs inside a zone but every time I attempt to do so I get the following message

```
zfs create -o casesensitivity=mixed -o nbmand=on -o mountpoint=/dat/share -o sharenfs=rw=@192.168.1.0/24 dat/share
cannot set property for 'dat': 'sharenfs' cannot be set in a non-global zone
```

So I take this as a sign that you can't use zfs nfs inside a zone so I've attempt to create the zfs nfs share out of the zone and I get the exact same error.

```
cannot create 'dat/share': 'mountpoint' cannot be set on dataset in a non-global zone
```

So now I am stumped and after a couple of hours of fiddling and googling around I am hoping someone can shed some light on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install nfs/server package in the zone first 
There are also following restrictions:

- Cross-zone LOFS mounts cannot be shared from zones.
- File systems mounted within zones cannot be shared from the global zone.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37628/gljbf.html